# Can I use an iPad Air (iPad 5) screen protector on my iPad Air 2 (iPad 6)

Tags: screen, ipad

I received an iPad Air 2 recently and am trying to order a screen protector for it. Can I use an iPad Air 1st Generation screen protecter? Are the width and height the same on both generations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are the same width and height. [You can check the measurements on Apple's website](https://www.apple.com/ipad/compare/). They're the same aside from the depth which has nothing to do with the screen protector.

```
          iPad Air 2              iPad Air
Height    9.4 inches (240 mm)     9.4 inches (240 mm)
Width     6.6 inches (169.5 mm)   6.6 inches (169.5 mm)
Depth     0.24 inch (6.1 mm)      0.29 inch (7.5 mm)
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. To better assist users, please provide a link to the information you are referencing.